# PHP CURL - HTTP Error 500 (The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout)

Tags: php, curl, fastcgi

I have enabled CURL on PHP and wanted to check that it is activated by a simple script as below.

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net");
    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

After testing on my local machine, I receive an internal server error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

What would be the causes of this error? The response shouldn't take too long so do not see how it can be a problem with timeouts etc?

Comment: To update this, I checked that it has been installed and all is ok, so I am still trying to work out what the issue could be here?

Comment: you can check this answer maybe it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/42620418/7335908